# A function that returns the length of a list of numbers that fulfilled 3 requirements

Tags: python, python-2.7

Function that prints the number of numbers in a list that fulfilled

1. f: divisible by
2. m: contains this no
3. n: within this range

Output should be 6 but I'm getting 0.

---

```
def number_contains(x,m):
return bool

def find_numbers(f,m,n):
z=[];
r = n+1;
y = range(1, r,1);

for x in y:
    if x % f == 0:
        if number_contains():
        z.append("x");
        else: 
        break
    else: 
    break
return len (z);

print(find_numbers(3,5,100))
```

---

Comment: What do you mean by _contains m_?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `break`, which ends the loop prematurely in your case, you should use `continue`, which will start another iteration.

```
def number_contains(x, m):
    return bool


def find_numbers(f, m, n):
    z = 0
    r = n+1
    y = range(1, r, 1)

    for x in y:
        if x % f == 0:
            if number_contains(x, m):
                z += 1
            else:
                continue
        else:
            continue
    return z


print(find_numbers(3, 5, 100))
```